# Mail gun is required for sending transaction emails in magento?

Tags: email-templates

My client asked to integrate mailgun in magento.But I'm confident that magento is enough to send all mails with out any issue?

Is there any extra advantage is there with mailgun over magento default transcation emails?

Comment: What does Mailgun means?

Comment: transactional email api service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mbalparda said, you don't need anything else to let magento send mails.

But using a service might be a good idea. Especially sending newsletters via another server avoids that you find yourself on black lists.

If you send a lot of emails this is a good idea too, because the services know how to avoid becoming spam marked mails.

Answer (score 1):

Magento has its own service for transactional emails, there is no need to install anything else. Most of the templates can be found under System - Transactional emails, [here](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates) is a guide to modify them.

On the other side, there are several services to handle emails like MailChimp and CampaignMonitor with their own modules and it can be configured pretty easily. At this point its a matter of opinion and not a necessity. If you found yourself comfortable integrating your own service you can do it, but its not mandatory since Magento has its own.